# Reverse engineer the value of a SUM in SQL / Impala

Tags: sql, sum, reverse-engineering, impala

I know its a longshot to figure this out but I was wondering if there is a possibility of finding out the rows a total comes from. My issue:

I've got a bunch of rows of transactions, 200,000 all with different values in them ranging from £0.50 to £1000.

I have a final sum of £10715601.32

This total has been generated by filtering a few things out and summing 'similar' transactions

I don't know which filter was used, would I be able to use this final sum to reverse calculate which transactions add up to this total?

Thanks!

Comment: Lots of work and trial and error.

Comment: Post the SQL you are using.  That might help us give you suggestions.